# Can I show keyboard shortcuts (hotkeys) on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, ui

When I right-click on a link in Firefox in Mac OS X, I get a menu like this:

[image: popup menu]

Now most of these items have keyboard shortcuts, so I can quickly press a single key instead of moving the mouse to a specific item. For example:

<kbd>t</kbd> = Open Link in New Tab
<kbd>k</kbd> = Save Link As...
 etc.

However I have no easy way of finding out what they are.

Is there a way to highlight or visualize these shortcuts, for example by underlining them like this:

[image: popup menu with keyboard shortcut markers] <sup>(photoshopped example)</sup>

This is also how Windows does it. Something like that possible on Mac as well?

P.S. This doesn't specifically relate to Firefox, just took this as an example but I would love to see keyboard shortcuts in general.

Comment: When I was trying to find a systematic answer to this question, I stumbled across a problem called KeyCue.  The demo version will display the keyboard shortcuts available in the current application.  Unfortunately, it does this using a database and so only some apps are supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can see system keyboard shortcuts in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts (or by [searching Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mac%20keyboard%20shortcuts)).

For keyboard shortcuts that correspond to menu items, they can be seen in the menus at the top of the screen, across from their corresponding commands.

Regarding the contextual menu, I just tested with the Desktop, Google Chrome and Apple's Messages. Pressing a letter takes me to the first item that *starts* with that letter. (For items that start with the same letter, also type the second [and third, etc.] letter to jump to the correct item.)

I don't believe Firefox's behavior is normal on Mac, so I would say filing a bug report with Firefox would be the most appropriate course of action. I'd think changing to how the rest of the OS works would be ideal. Short of that, putting the shortcut right-aligned across from the corresponding item would work best, since that would match how menu bar menus work.