# How to show keyboard shortcuts in menus?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I found that shortcuts for certain functions are shown on Windows right next to the name of the functions when we do right click or something, but not on MacOS, which can be time wasting when we have to look up shortcuts ourselves. Can we change this setting?

[image: right click on Windows]

[image: Right click on Windows]

[image: Right click on MAC]

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255054/can-i-show-keyboard-shortcuts-hotkeys-on-mac-os-x?rq=1

Comment: There used to be https://www.mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/ but this will not work with Sonoma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, macOS also shows keyboard shortcuts in the menubar menus.

However, it doesn't show them (anymore?) in Contextual Menus (e.g. on a right-click).

[image]

I doubt there's a method of enabling that. You should send feedback to Apple that this is what you would like.

Comment: Out of curiosity I checked back on a Snow Leo VM… no commands in contextual menus there either, so I'd say it probably never did.

Comment: @Tetsujin Nor in Classic MacOS, neither!